# Azure security - lock account to prevent accidental object deletion

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying out Azure and it is incredibly easy to create Storage, VHDD's and VMs

The problem is , it is also incredibly easy to DELETE them too!
And from what I gather, once deleted they are permanently gone!

Is there any way to lock storage containers so that they can't be deleted by accident?

Or is there some sort of security feature that can be switched on to force authentication before deletion?

If not, this seems an incredible oversight of the platform - what happens if a session to the Portal is hijacked - somebody could go ahead and delete everything without additional authentication!!

Comment: I agree, I can't believe there isn't a simple "padlock" that you can engage which would then require some kind of additional step before allowing deletion. We once lost a storage account with 300 containers and over 100,000 blobs because of a single incorrect mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Storage - 
You are correct, once deleted a blob/VHD/etc is permanently gone.  An account key does give complete control over / access to an account.  However, there are several tools you can use to mitigate these possibilities:

- Blobs support taking snapshots; you can create snapshots of a blob to preserve the historical state of blobs.  When trying to delete a blob, the user would have to take the additional step of specifying to delete the snapshots.  This can help protect against accident, but not malice.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh488361.aspx
- If you have multiple accounts, you can use as AzCopy to backup blobs (and VHD’s) from one account to another.  This can protect against leaking of a storage access key.  Here's a blog post about AzCopy: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx

Comment: This does not prevent the accidental deletion of the entire storage account.